# Upgrading windows 7 to windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

I had a corrupted windows 7 install, so I formatted the hard drive and installed windows 10. When I go into the computer, it wants the registration key. I have the windows 7 registration key, but it won't work for the windows 10 version. I know you can upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10, but I don't know what I am doing wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You need a Windows 10 key to upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 10. The free upgrade program is no longer active.

.

During the installation process, you can skip the product key input and continue with the installation. However, after 30 days, you will get a notification that you need to activate the OS with a product key to continue using it.

Comment: Evidently you can still upgrade for FREE!>>>>>>>https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to reinstall and activate your copy of Windows 7 so that Windows has an active installation to inherit key entitlement from and download the [Windows 10 Media Creation Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). Despite Microsoft’s precious announcement that this program had ended, both recent personal experience and [ZDNet’s article updated in September](https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/) indicate that this procedure still works.

Download and install any drivers your system needs to function as if it were going to be using Windows 7 just to avoid any snags during installation. I've run into a few instances of it failing Windows 10's pre-install eligibility check due to missing drivers it wasn't able to locate on its own in the past.

Run the media creation tool and select "Upgrade this PC now"  when it asks what you'd like the media creator to do. It should offer to automatically download any service packs it needs to handle the transition and updates to Windows 10 deemed appropriate for the system itself. From there, it'll take a few hours to download and install, and you should come back to a fresh and fully activated copy of Windows 10.

Comment: Did it end a few days ago? This procedure worked for me last week, and ZDNet confirmed that it still works a month ago. https://www.zdnet.com/article/heres-how-you-can-still-get-a-free-windows-10-upgrade/

Comment: Thats just crazy, i guess they want more W7-8 upgrades to happen. Thanks for the link!

Comment: You should make that an answer @Coda

Comment: @Coda - Why are you asking a question within your answer?

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the heads up. Not sure how that ended up there. Fixed and added ZDNet link.

Answer (score -1):

"so I formatted the hard drive and installed windows 10" - So it was not really an upgrade, you did a clean install of windows 10.

The upgrade program has ended but still I recommend you try the following :

- Install Windows 7 again after formatting your hard disk (Remember to backup your Imp data)
- Activate Windows 7 using the registration key you have.
- Now that your Windows 7 is activated, run the windows 10 setup from within windows 7 just like you would install any typical software.
- In the windows 10 setup window choose to "Upgrade this PC" , I don't remember the exact wording but you will get an option to upgrade the current PC/operating system.
- Once you proceed with the on screen instructions I hope your Windows 10 will be activated. Do give it a try and let us know what happened. Good Luck.